# How do I automatically install New Relic extension using Azure ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation, azure-resource-manager

I am using a azure arm template to create a web app in azure. Now I need to install New Relic Extension in the webapps which will be created using this template. So I was unable to find specific json format. Please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a try to add the json code snipped in the ARM template.

```
 "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "NewRelic.Azure.WebSites",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
          }
        }
      ],
```

I created a demo for it. The following is my detail steps. About the name of the extension please refer to the [NewRelic.Azure.WebSites](https://www.siteextensions.net/stats/packages/NewRelic.Azure.WebSites?groupby=Version).

**1.    Create an Azure Resource Group Project.**
[image]

**2.    Select the Web App project template**
[image]

**3.    Just demo for web site extension so I delete the unnecessary resource**

[image]

**4.    Add the snipped code in the ARM template**

[image]

**5.    Deploy the website via Visual Studio**

[image]
[image]

**6.    Check the Website in the Azure portal**

[image]

The demo ARM template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "NewRelic.Azure.WebSites",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It worked but Do we need to configure the "properties"??

Answer (score 0):

```
"resources":[{
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "NewRelic.Azure.WebSites.Extension",
      "type": "siteextensions",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('appServiceName'))]"
      ]
    }]
```

The name is now NewRelic.Azure.Websites.Extension. You should give your App Service Name in the variable appServiceName in this case.