# How to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone extension in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I want to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone extension through my Azure App Service ARM template file. At this moment, I need open Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 15.5 preview and click my app, then select "Attach Snapshot Debugger". It will prompt me to install the Snapshot Debugger extension to the app service, and I have to restart the app service after it has been installed. The feature is great for production debugging but how can I have it ready there when my app is deployed?

I also found a Nuget package has [the same name](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone/). Should I just add this package into my app? What is the relationship between the extension and the package? I know this feature is in preview but hope someone could have some clue.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it as answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone extension through my Azure App Service ARM template file

We could do that with adding following code in the Website ARM template. You could get the detail steps from another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507711/how-do-i-automatically-install-new-relic-extension-using-azure-arm-template/40582242#40582242) just change the extension name to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone`. I test it on my side, it works correctly.

```
"resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
          }
        }
      ],
```

> Should I just add this package into my app?

I also test Asp.net and Asp.net core project with the nuget installed, but after it published to azure, there is no extension installed.

> What is the relationship between the extension and the package?

According to the extension description,  it is the  Nuget package for Visual Studio Snapshot Debugger standalone site extension.
We could get detail info with Azure kudu tool(https://{WebAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net) to check the installed extension that under

```
D:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SnapshotDebugger.AzureAppServices.Standalone
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try this out and mark if works. Looks promising!